# Rewrite problems with mod_rewrite and Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

This question might look intimidating. No, it's simple but thoroughly explained. So please keep on reading.

I need to make a multilingual page (English and Spanish) and I want to use this segment to route each language:

mysite/**en**/mycontroller/mymethod

These are the rules I made in .htaccess and their description:

```
# Rewrite url removing language segment and appending it as a request variable
RewriteRule ^(es|en)/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [L]

# Remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|images|scripts|robots.txt|sitemap.xml) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

There is something I'm not doing correctly:

The 1st rule is creating the request variable **lang** correctly, but the URL is still being routed without removing the language segment (**en|es**), which **causes an error** because Codeigniter assumes (so I think) to expect a controller called **"en"** or **"es"**. I could eventually get rid of this segment in the CI routes, but since I'm doing it in .htaccess there is no need to repeat it again. As far as I know, this segment shouldn't exist anymore after the rewrite.

**Note**: I don't want to use CI routes for this particular case because of these reasons:

- They don't work by default with appended request variables,
- I don't want to use visible request variables in public URL's (no way enabling them in config file),
- Passing the request variable as a parameter segment would mean the need to retrieve it in the index or whatever else requested method,
- I want to process this before, within the constructor (retrieving $_GET('lang') in it).

Just in case this helps, these are the $_GET and $_SERVER variables (not all) dumped just when entering index.php:

Example URL: `http://localhost/mysite/en/portfolio`

$_GET:

```
Array
(
    [lang] => en
)
```

$_SERVER:

```
Array
(
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => C:/xampp/htdocs
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => C:/xampp/htdocs
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/index.php
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => lang=en
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /mysite/portfolio
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => lang=en
    [REQUEST_URI] => /mysite/en/portfolio
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /mysite/index.php
    [PATH_INFO] => /portfolio
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio
    [PHP_SELF] => /mysite/index.php/portfolio
)
```

The same URL without the language segment works perfectly and enters the Portfolio controller:
`http://localhost/mysite/portfolio`

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with CI, but, if I understand it correctly, you want to get a [REQUEST_URI] => /mysite/portfolio?

Comment: @Muc: I suppose that's what I want, as long as it is what Codeigniter uses to route the request in order to retrieve the controller and its method. That's the default behaviour of Codeigniter: `www.site.com/controller/method/param1/param2/..`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code once.........

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This way I will not get the **lang** GET variable to know in what language the data must be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `RewriteRule ^(es|en)/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(es|en)/(.*) index.php/$2?lang=$1 [L]`

Comment: Hello @swatkins. Your suggested rule behaves just the same. It only works if I do this: `localhost/mysite/portfolio`, but not with the language segment `localhost/mysite/en/portfolio`. The request variable is created but the request uri is not rewritten to delete the **"en"**.